# Web browser usage census map?

Tags: geolocation, mashup

Does anyone know of a web application that will display the types/versions of browsers people use overlaid over google maps?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is close: http://gs.statcounter.com/

It doesn't have a map, but it does a pretty good job of giving a broad overview of what people are browsing on.

Comment: http://gs.statcounter.com/ now has a map feature that records the top browser by region for up to the last 90 day period.